# Why is the direction of acceleration not dependent on velocity whereas the direction of velocity depends on displacement?

Tags: kinematics

My textbook says that as v=dr/dt, the direction of velocity(instantaneous) is perpendicular to the position vector. (Drawing a graph of position against time, the tangent to the position vector is the velocity vector at that point).
a=dv/dt, and so the same logic should apply to acceleration. However, we can't say that the acceleration vector has a direction perpendicular to the velocity vector at all points. It is solely determined by the force acting on it. This is all according to my textbook.
Now, I do not understand. If you can draw a relationship between position vectors and velocity vectors as shown above, what prevents us from drawing a similar relationship between velocity and acceleration? Mathematically, both relationships seem to be identical.

Comment: The tangent need not be perpendicular to the displacement vector. That is only true for circular paths.

Comment: We can say that v~dr and a~dv, so: Velocity points to the same direction as displacement, acceleration points to the same direction as the change in velocity. How would the perpendicularity of a and dr follow from these two?

Comment: @FellowTraveller Oh, my bad. That's exactly what I missed. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact both velocity and acceleration are along the direction of difference between their parent vectors. Velocity is along the difference of position vectors (final position - initial position); and acceleration is along difference of velocity vectors (final velocity - initial velocity). For instantaneous values we simply squeeze the time interval to almost zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can understand it like this.

Let the position vector of a particle is 
$$\mathbf{r}=r \hat{r}(\theta)$$
Thus the velocity vector will be $$\vec{v}=\frac{dr}{dt}\hat{r}(\theta)+r\frac{d\hat{r}(\theta)}{dt}$$
$$\hat{r}=cos\theta \hat{i} +sin \theta \hat{j}$$
$$\frac{d\hat{r}(\theta)}{dt}=\dot{\theta}\hat{\theta}$$
Similearly you can show using $\hat{\theta}=-sin\theta \hat{i} +cos \theta \hat{j}$ that

$$ \frac{d\hat{\theta}}{dt}=-\dot{\theta}\hat{r}$$
back to velocity expression you get $$\vec{v}=\dot{r}\hat{r}+r\theta \hat{\theta}$$
Similear proof for acceleration 
$$\vec{a}=(\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta^2})\hat{r}+(r\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{r}\dot{\theta} )\hat{\theta}$$
That's proove it is not necessary that velocity vector is perpendicular to position vector.All have different directions.